# Improper integral problem not easy to solve with exponential in the denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there an analytical way to solve the following integral ?

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+1\right) \left(e^{2 \pi  x}-1\right)} \, dx$

The solution provided by Mathematica is $\gamma -\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> It's somehow related to the
> [Second Binet Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html). See
> [$\ds{\mathbf{\color{black}{6.3.21}}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5mm,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty }{2x \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}\pars{\expo{2\pi x} - 1}}\,\dd x}
\\ = &\
2\int_{0}^{\infty }
{x \over \pars{x^{2} + \color{red}{1}^{2}}\pars{\expo{2\pi x} - 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{\ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z} - \Psi\pars{z}}_{\ z\ =\ \color{red}{1}} =
-\,{1 \over 2} -\ \overbrace{\Psi\pars{1}}^{\ds{-\gamma}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\gamma - {1 \over 2}} \approx 0.772
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, there is an extra 2 in the second integral.

Comment: @GeorgePa1 Fixed. Thanks.